# How to access a variable declared within another function

Tags: python, function, class, variables, global

I am trying to access a variable declared in another function, but I got

```
ERROR:
AttributeError: 'Myclass1' object has no attribute 'myDictIn'
```

The code I used is as follows:

```
class Myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def myadd(self): 
        x=self.myDictIn # tried accessing variable declared in another function
        return x
    def mydict(self):  #variable declared in this function
        myDictIn={1:[1,2,3,4],3:[4,5,6,7]}
        self.myDictIn= myDictIn
        return myDictIn
inst=Myclass1() # Created instance
inst.myadd() # Accessing function where I am using an variable declared in another function
```

Also I tried declaring it as global

```
 def mydict(self):  #variable declared in this function
        global myDictIn
        myDictIn={1:[1,2,3,4],3:[4,5,6,7]}
        self.myDictIn= myDictIn
        return myDictIn
```

but still got same ERROR

Please help me ....
Actually I need to access an variable generated in one function and use it within another Function....Also
I tried.....

1. Declaring as class variable (before **init** and after declaring class name)
2. Declaring that variable within **init**
   Those 2 approaches lead to further errors

So I must be able to access varibale generated within one function and use it in another function. Please assist me to find an answer

Comment: What do you mean "typecast to know the size of the list"? Can you give a *complete example*? And why don't you just not "convert to array then append to the list" and work with the array?

Comment: You appear to be interested in `A[0]`, not `A`. How did `A` get defined in the first  place?

Comment: Also, there is not "typecast" operator in Python. Although the term is used in the general sense of "convert this object to an object of another type," I don't think this usage is really helpful, and it isn't like type-casting in languages like Java or C.

Comment: Thanks Juanpa, I mean
"typecast to know the size of the list"?
I intend to measure the number of elements in A

Can you give a complete example?
The code is very lengthy 1000 lines

I want to extract only 5000 elements in every item
eg:
temp=A[0] # Access first item in the above eg
temp[0:5000] # expected output

Answer (score 0):

Your instance never calls the method mydict.  Remember that python is interpreted line-by-line the self.myDictIn will not be assigned at that point.

Instead, why don't you write self.myDictIn= .... in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks The Doc,

I made it and declared within __init__. The output I received is as expected. 
    def __init__(self):
        self.myDictIn = {1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}

What if, the variable must be used after assignment from another function....Is there a possibilities ?
    def mydict(self):  
        myDictIn = {1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}
        return myDictIn

Comment: That's fine as long as you're absolutely sure that you don't try and access the self.myDictIn property before you've declared it.  It is more unusual to declare class variables in a method other than the __init__ although sometimes you have to.   However, you'd better declare self.DictIn = {} at least in the __init__ constructor and some other function somewhere else fills it in.

Comment: If we declare 
self.myDictIn={}

then whenever you call myDictIn within any function then the answer will always be 
{}

What if,....I want to reflect the modification made by another function within a function

Answer (score 0):

In myadd(self), declare myDictIn as global. As you know variables need to be declared/assigned before using it. If programme encounters myDictIn before assigned, it throws the error. So please declare myDictIn before programme encounters myDictIn.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks unMask and I would like to let you the output I got by making it global.....


class Myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def myadd(self): 
        x = self.myDictIn
        print(x)
        return x

    def mydict(self):
        global myDictIn
        myDictIn = {1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}
        self.myDictIn = myDictIn
        return myDictIn

inst = Myclass1()
inst.myadd()

expected output:
{1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}

actual output:
AttributeError: 'Myclass1' object has no attribute 'myDictIn'

Comment: You've declared global myDictIn in mydict instead of myadd

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need a `getter` and `setter` here, you can use python [`properties`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) to do that:

```
class Myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_value):
        self.myDictIn = dict_value

    @property
    def myDictIn(self):
      print(self.__myDictIn)
      return self.__myDictIn

    @myDictIn.setter
    def myDictIn(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            raise TypeError("dict_value must be a dict")
        self.__myDictIn = value

dict_value = {1: [1, 2, 3 ,4], 3: [4, 5, 6, 7]}
inst = Myclass1(dict_value)
inst.myDictIn # {1: [1, 2, 3 ,4], 3: [4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

This way, you can still change the value of `MyDictIn` easily

```
inst.myDictIn = {1: [1, 2, 3]}
inst.myDictIn # {1: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Thanks Max however I am still unable to print myDictIn variable within myadd....

class Myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myDictIn = None

    def myadd(self): 
        x = self.myDictIn
        print(x)
        return x

    def mydict(self):
        myDictIn = {1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}
        self.myDictIn = myDictIn
        return myDictIn

inst = Myclass1()
inst.myadd()

Actual Output:
None

Expected Output:
{1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}

Comment: Yes because you have to run the method `mydict` first. You should call in the `__init__` method. I will update my answer if you struggle to do it

Comment: Max, Actually I need to access an variable generated in one function and use it within another Function....Also
I tried declaring as class variable (before __init__ and after declaring class name)
Additionally I tried using within __init__
Those 2 approach lead to further errors 

So I must be able to access varibale generated within one function and use it in another function

Comment: You can use `self.myDictIn` in every methods of the class `MyClass1`. Do you need to use the variable outside the class? Please provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: class Myclass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def myadd(self): 
        x = self.__myDictIn
        print(x)
    def mydict(self):  
        self.__myDictIn={1: [1, 2, 3 ,4] ,3 : [4, 5, 6, 7]}
        return self.myDictIn
inst = Myclass1()
inst.myadd()

Output:
AttributeError

Please let me know why this didnt work inspite of declaring a variable as __myDictIn.

Comment: Use my codebase and modify it. Same problem as before, if you don't define the variable myDictIn in `__init__` you should not be able to access it afterward. You cannot `pass` init OR you can use `global` in every method and define the var outside the class. But I wouldn't recommend it.